# perl script to search all files in folder

Tags: perl

I have one folder that contains more number of xml files and extract some specific information form xml files. I used libxml to extract wanted information one xml and I succeded but now how can I extract from folder and each xml file using perl script. I tried like this for one xml file:

```
use warnings;
use strict;
use XML::LibXML::Reader;

my $file;
open( $file, 'formal.xml');
my $reader = XML::LibXML::Reader->new( IO => $file ) 
    or die ("unable to open file");
my %hash;
while ($reader->nextElement( 'nuber' ) ) {
    my $Number = $reader->readInnerXml();
    $reader->nextElement( 'data' ); 
    my $information = $reader->readOuterXml(); 
    $nums{$Number}= $information;
    print( "  NUMBER:$Number\n" );
    print( " Information:$information\n" );
}
print my $num=keys%hash;
close($file);
```

Above code working properly and extracted what I want. Now I need script that will search all files in the folder and extract the same information from all files.

Comment: The above code cannot be working properly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

use [File::Find](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc/File%3a%3aFind).

Your code cannot be working properly as it is. Here is an untested script that might do what you want.

```
use warnings; use strict;

use Carp;
use File::Find;
use File::Spec::Functions qw( canonpath );
use XML::LibXML::Reader;

die "Need directories\n" unless @ARGV;

my %hash;
find(
    sub {
        my $file = $_;
        my $path = canonpath $File::Find::name;

        return unless -f $path;
        return unless $file =~ /[.]xml\z/i;

        extract_information($path, \%hash);
        return;
    },
    @ARGV
);

use Data::Dumper;
print Dumper \%hash;

sub extract_information {
    my ($path, $hash) = @_;

    my $ret = open my $xmlin, '<', $path;
    unless ($ret) {
        carp "Cannot open '$path': $!";
        return;
    }

    my $reader = XML::LibXML::Reader->new(IO => $xmlin);
    unless ($reader) {
        carp "Cannot create reader using '$path'";
        return;
    }

    while ($reader->nextElement('number')) {
        my $Number = $reader->readInnerXml();

        $reader->nextElement( 'data' );
        my $information = $reader->readOuterXml();

        $hash->{$path}{$Number} = $information;
    }

    close $xmlin
        or carp "Cannot close '$path': $!";

    return;
}
```

Comment: Hi,I tried to run your code, it giving output like" need directories". I have doubt where should I specify directories.I have one folder which contains sub folders and in that sub folders I have my .xml files. can you tell me what should I have to do now? I studied the file::find module and file::spec::functions but I am in little bit confusion.@sinan

Comment: Directory names are in `@ARGV`. `canonpath` is used to make directory separators consistently Windows style `\`. Doesn't make a difference in function, but filenames in messages look better if all directory separators are the same, and correct for the platform.

Comment: I need to declare directory names in @ARGV.

Comment: i declare one directory to @ARGV and i tried to run it gives some errors like. "use of uninitialized  $path in sub routine "extract_information" line my $ret = open my $xmlin, '<', $path; and use of uninitialized $path in concatination in the next line.

Comment: @pavani: Untested means untested. I had a typo in `extract_information`. Fixed now. Incidentally, you should have been able to see where the problem was.

Comment: Thank you very much, it helped me alot and sorry for asking one more question i extracted one more tag from xml data if you see in the above code. but how can i print the string value in hash. how can i print the hash with three elements like number, string, information.